# Bootstrap layout - aligning icon on one level with heading

Tags: html, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, icons, alignment

I need to create layout using bootstrap, but I'm struggling with aligning icon (as it seen on an image). It should be without left margin and on the same level as article title. I tried different containers for icon and other content separately, but it didn't work out.

Code as it is now:

```
<div class="container">
        <span id="article"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></span>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
        <h2>Article title</h2>
            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
        <button id="button" class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div></div>
```

[layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNs15.jpg)
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted your CSS it's hard to show exactly, but try a negative margin.  I don't know that bootstrap has a built in class for this, so you may need to make one that has the correct varying amounts of margin based on window size since you're offset will vary based on window size.  Basically you need the exact same amount of margin as is used in the offset, but negative on the span.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
    <h2><span id="article" style="margin-left:-20px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></span> Article title</h2>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
    <button id="button" class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, and it does work with negative margin, however is it OK to use negative values? For some reason I thought that using them is a bad habit, or it's not?

Comment: As far as I know it's fine.  I do it regularly.  You can get into trouble if you have overflow:hidden; because that will hide the negative part, but normally it works fine because overflow in shown by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code which divides grids and displays the icon on the first grid:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <h2>Article title</h2>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    <button id="button" class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's actually gives the alignment I need

Comment: It looks to me like this will cause problems on smaller screens because `col-md-2` is mixed with `col-xs-10`.  It should probably be `col-xs-2` rather than `col-md-2`.

Comment: You are right, I somehow write in my code xs for both and didn't notice this  mix-up here